# Error: Cannot access contents of the page. Extension manifest must request permission to access the respective host

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I create a popup when webpage button is click and now i want to access the webpage content but it cant happened. I write the permission in manifest file but error comes **Cannot access contents of the page. Extension manifest must request permission to access the respective host.**
Here is the code of popup:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (message, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (message.action === 'openExtension') {
 // console.log("working");
  chrome.windows.create({
    url: "cover.html",
    type: "popup",
    focused: true,
    width: 400,
    height: 600,
    top: 0,
   // left: screen.width - 400,
}, () => {
    console.log("Opened popup!")
})
```

And manifest file is

```
{
    "name":"Sample",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "This is Sample",
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "content_scripts":
     [
      {
      "matches":["https://www.upwork.com/ab/proposals/job/*/apply/"],
      
      "js":["content.js"],
        "css":["style.css"]
      }],
    "action":{
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_popup":"cover.html"
    },
    "background": {
      "service_worker": "background.js"
    },
   
   "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "scripting"
    
 
  ],
  "host_permissions": ["https://www.upwork.com/ab/proposals/job/*/apply/"]
    
}
```

and i want to access the content of page :

```
 function  getJobDesc(limits,tone) {
           
                const title = document.title;
                const jobDes = document.getElementById("up-truncation-1").textContent;
          
                console.log(title);
                console.log(jobDes);
            
                
               
                
                   const url = "https://aidemo.provelopers.net/api/gpt-3/generate";
                   const data ={
                    job: jobDes,
                    limit: limits,
                    tone: tone
                   };
             
                 
                    const other_params = {
                        headers : { "content-type" : "application/json; charset=UTF-8" , "Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"*"},
                        body :JSON.stringify( data),
                        method : "POST",
                        mode : "cors",
                        
                    };
            
             return  fetch(url, other_params)
                        .then(function(response) {
                            
                          
                            if (response.ok) {
                                console.log('working');
                                return response.json();
                            } else {
                               throw new Error("Could not reach the API: " + response.statusText);
                            }
                        }).then(function(data) {
                          console.log(data);
                          return data;
                       
                         
                        }).catch(function(error) {
                            console.log(error);
                        
                        });
                   
                
               
              
            }
           
    
            chrome.scripting.executeScript({
                target: { tabId: tab.id },
                args:[limits,tone],
                func: getJobDesc,
                //        files: ['contentScript.js'],  // To call external file instead
            }).then(function(data) {
                var element = document.getElementById("proposal");
                if (element) {
                
                   element.value =data[0].result;
                
                }
                else{
                    console.log('errrorrrrrr');
                }
            });

        });
```

Thus,
In manifest file i write the permission of respective host but error comes
**Cannot access contents of the page. Extension manifest must request permission to access the respective host.**

Comment: Nothing in the posted code can generate this error, so it's probably an old error which you can clear by clicking the trashcan icon or the `Clear all` button. In case you use chrome.scripting.executeScript, add the code to the question.